# jQuery IE10 behavior of css('background-position')

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, background-position

I have simple code snippet:

```
$('div').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
alert( $('div').css('background-position') );
```

And I expect that I will receive '0px 0px', but I have received "0% 0%" in IE10.
Also I noticed that jquery `.css` returns results with percent always when it's equal 0px, e.g "0px 50px" => "0% 50px" in IE10.

Is it jQuery bug? or it's IE10 bug?

You could [try it on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/emacow/1/edit)

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a change in IE 10, wouldn't necessarily call it a bug yet :) but returns the input strings in IE 9.

Comment: IE9 behavior is as expected. IE10 - not. And seems like it's jQuery issue, cuz it works fine, when we do it without jQuery: http://jsbin.com/emacow/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on values being the same as what you give. Browsers can and frequently do normalise the values you give them.

For example, if you give the colour `#ffffff`, the browser may change it to `rgb(255,255,255)` internally. Similarly, a length of `0px` may be converted to just `0`.

NEVER rely on the style property being exactly what you told it. If you need to know, either use a variable to keep track of it, or use something like a class to change styles as needed.

Comment: Okay, I want to perform testing of background position change in my spinner. How can I do that if I can't rely on .css property?

Comment: Well, the background position won't just change by itself. Whatever code changes the background position, you can adjust to also call a function.

Comment: Yep, good point. I could test that variable and not rely on .css(); But anyway it's strange: http://jsbin.com/emacow/5/edit :) It works okay even in IE10.